# How can I build a live Youtube video 'likes' count on my website *without refreshing* using nodejs, express, YouTube data api

Tags: node.js, express, youtube-data-api

Currently, I have figured out how to make API calls to YouTube Data Api and getting the number of likes of any video. And I'm making the call every minute. I do not know, however, how to update the corresponding element in html with the updated value.

Previously, I had made API calls in app.get and then updated using response.send() but that meant that my number would only update everytime I reload the page. Then I took the code block out of app.get but realised I had no way of update the UI with updated numbers from the API call.

I would like to ask how I can go about doing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for that, you can use WebSocket module

Websocket is just a protocol like HTTP and it provides a persistent connection between a client and server that both parties can use to start sending data at any time.

Websocket is also provided by many front-end frameworks such as flutter, native android, react native etc.

Comment: how would you create connection between your UI to youtube api or your api to youtube api?